# Misunderstandable grammar structure

Tags: phrase-usage

I was reading model answers on CAE writing part and in one of the essays found out a grammar structure I misunderstand:

> *In my opinion, whilst any facility would be a positive improvement, I have distinct reservations about the addition of a history museum to the town. To begin with, I think that museums are rather dry, boring places and a new museum would be my last choice as a solution to **liven up** the town. Moreover, a history museum would have a very limited appeal and only be of interest to history buffs and would be unlikely to appeal to the town's younger generation.*

In bold, why should we use here this grammar structure, but not "live up"?

Comment: What question are you asking, exactly? Do you have a problem with 'liven up'?

Comment: I think you mean that you don't understand it. _Misunderstand_ means to understand something in the wrong way. To _liven up_ the town is to make it more lively. We can't use _live up_ in this sense.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of the phrase [**live it up**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/live_it_up), which is rather different to the use of **liven up** here. The first is intransitive, the second is transitive. Another similar phrase is [**live up to**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/live_up_to) but is further off-target, meaning to meet someone's expectations.

Comment: I mean, why should we use "liveN up", but not "live up"? Could you give a reference to the grammar rule?

Comment: Oh, I understood: "liven" is a base verb! Thanks for your support! Just confused this word with "lived"... :-)

Comment: [to misunderstand and not understand are not the same thing.]

Comment: Thank you! Could you give the appropriate substitutuent for "not understand" (one word, if possible)?